# Intel Xeon CPU is running low but clock frequency is up 100%+

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, fan, workstation

I've got a strange problem with my new Windows 10 computer.
I recently bought a laptop workstation with Intel Xeon Chip E series.

When I did the first boot the fan started spinning loud and then stopped. And it repeted until I finished install all windows updates. When it starts spinning it does not last for a long time, most of the time is less than a minute.

Now that all the windows 10 updates are done the fans does not spin that loud or doesn't spin at all. But I noticed that when I stream a movie from the computer to the TV over the network the funs start to spin again very loud for less than a minute and then stops. I noticed that when the spinning start the CPU usage is less than 10% but the clock frequency is above 120%. Why is that happening?

Now I have installed ARCGIS, for my work,a single core application, and it is doing the same thing when I just move around a simple satellite image in the application (I didn't even started with the image processing). I really don't understand why is this happening. I bought this machine specially because of my work and I'm not even doing now heavy staff and it is already spinning like crazy.

The laptop that I have is HP Zbook G6 17 and I think it has a very good airflow system. When I was checking the system while working I noticed that the Graphics Card was not being used in any moment both during the streaming and displaying the image. Is this normal? Is everything Okay with the computer?

Can anyone help understand why is it happening and what can I do to solve it?

**This is my machine configuration:**

Intel Xeon E2286M @2.40GHZ
8 Cores
32 GB RAM
Nvidea Quadro RTX 4000

Comment: Did you try updating BIOS on this computer?

Comment: YES, I have updated the BIOS and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually 3 different aspects:

- The thermal management in your Laptop doesn't only care for the CPU, but also for the GPU. A Quadro RTX 4000 will produce quite some heat even with low load (such as displaying an image and moving it around), so there is airflow needed to remove this heat.
- Windows updates are CPU intensive on a single thread. This means, that while the total CPU usage might be only 1/16 (8 cores x 2 Threads), this one thread maxes out. So not only will the clock frequency go up, the thermal management will kick in as well
- The words "Workstation" and "Laptop" don't go well together: The perceived noise level is dependent not only on the amount of heat to remove, but even more so on the fan size and the aerodynamic properties of the air ducts. Obviously the constraint space in a laptop is at a huge disadvantage her: Fans have to be much smaller (thus turn squared-much faster), additionally the design headroom for optimum air ducts is close to zero.

All together this means, that this sort of performance in a laptop doesn't come quiet.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Based on what you said I'd like to add few more things that I think we help understand which computer I'm using. The laptop that I have is HP Zbook G6 17 and I think it has a very good airflow system.

Comment: When I was checking the system while working I noticed that the Graphics Card was not being used in any moment both during the streaming and displaying the image. Is this normal? Is everything Okay with the computer?

Comment: A very good airflow system in a laptop is typically worse than a mediocre airflow system in a desktop - it's a matter of physics.

Comment: A graphics card is used whenever your coputer shows ANYTHING on the screen.

Comment: I agree with you but in this case, I was pointing to the Nvidia Quadro graphic card. During these uses, it was at 0%. But the Intel UHD Graphics was around 5-10%.

Comment: You should add the fact, that you have dual GPUs in your OQ